# Overriding PromptService in newer XULRunner

Tags: xpcom, xulrunner

Our application uses embedded xulrunner. We override the default PromptService to provide custom dialogs for alert, prompt, etc by

```
componentRegistrar.RegisterFactory (PROMPTSERVICE_CID, aClassName, aContractID, MyPromptServiceFactory);
```

where,

```
PROMPTSERVICE_CID is "a2112d6a-0e28-421f-b46a-25c0b308cbd0"
CONTRACT_ID is "@mozilla.org/embedcomp/prompt-service;1"
```

When using XULRunner 1.9.* versions, this works perfectly and the call comes to `MyPromptSerivceFactory`. But, this doesn't work on newer XULRunner versions (>= 4.0)

I have modified the `PROMPTSERVICE_CID` to `"7ad1b327-6dfa-46ec-9234-f2a620ea7e00"` (copied from `nsPrompter.manifest`). While registering the factory I get the error `NS_ERROR_FACTORY_EXISTS`.

If I continue to use the old `PROMPTSERVICE_CID`, then `nsIPromptService2` is not used instead `nsIWindowCreator2.CreateChromeWindow2` is used to display alerts and prompts.

I have googled on this, but I couldn't find a solution to either fix the `NS_ERROR_FACTORY_EXISTS` error or for `MyPromptServiceFactory` to be used.

Any help/suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be better to use the existing prompt service the way Firefox does it rather than replace it. If you look at [nsPrompter.openPrompt()](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/d51bd1645a2f/toolkit/components/prompts/src/nsPrompter.js#l489), before opening a modal dialog it will try to locate and call a JavaScript function `getTabModalPrompt()` in the window containing the browser. It expects to get a [`promptBox` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/promptBox) back and will call methods `appendPrompt()` and `removePrompt()` on it. Obviously, you don't have to give it a `promptBox` element, just something that behaves similarly - and displays a message any way you like.

But if you really want to replace system components, you shouldn't duplicate prompter's CID - use your own one but `@mozilla.org/prompter;1` as contract ID (the old contract ID is for backwards compatibility only).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Using @mozilla.org/prompter;1 as contract ID, I could fix the problem. How to get my own CID to be used in RegisterFactory?

Comment: @lakshmip: Just generate some UUID. E.g. use http://www.famkruithof.net/uuid/uuidgen

Comment: Sorry for necro'ing this really old thread, but is there any reference on exactly how to do this with xulrunner? Nothing Google-fu gives me seems to work...

Comment: @Kyudos: If you need references on XULRunner - you are out of luck. XULRunner is very much under-documented and this won't change since Mozilla isn't putting any effort into it any more. They don't even offer it for download any more. But if you really want to give it a shot, studying Firefox source code is your best chance.

Comment: Thanks @WladimirPalant. I did get the override to work eventually - largely through trial and error!